# How to select Distinct UNION with priority 1st table

Tags: sql, sql-server, union-all

How to write the distinct Union query with ignore one column in all the tables.

I would like to select the data from two tables with same field name and insert into 3rd table but data should be unique except one field (1st table row number  should consider)

```
CREATE TABLE table_a
(
    id INTEGER ,
    name TEXT,
    rownumber TEXT
) ;
CREATE TABLE table_b
(
    id INTEGER ,
    name TEXT,
    rownumber TEXT
) ;

CREATE TABLE table_c
(
    id INTEGER,
    name TEXT,
    rownumber TEXT
) ;

INSERT INTO 
   table_a
   (id, name, rownumber)
VALUES
   (1001, 'Alex' , '111'),
   (1002, 'John' , '112'),
   (1003, 'Max'  , '113'),
   (1004, 'Joly'  , '114'), 

INSERT INTO 
   table_b
   (id, name, rownumber)
VALUES
   (1005, 'Angila', '211'),
   (1002, 'John'  , '212'),
   (1006, 'Tim'   , '213'),
```

Expected  Table_c Should be unique **id** and **name** from "table_a" + "table_b" and "rowversion" should consider from the table_a

Result as :-

```
   (1001, 'Alex' , '111'),
   (1002, 'John' , '112'),  // From 1st table
   (1003, 'Max'  , '113'),
   (1004, 'Joly'  , '114'),

   (1005, 'Angila', '211'),
   (1006, 'Tim'   , '213'),
```

Answer (score 5):

How about using `not exists`?

```
select a.*
from table_a a
union all
select b.*
from table_b b
where not exists (select 1 from table_a a where a.id = b.id and a.name = b.name);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for quick response

Comment: @skt How about accepting the response as an answer so that anyone with a similar problem in the future can find the "answer". That is how SO is designed to work.